# C++ creating a loop for data entry if does not meet criteria

Tags: c++

It has been a long time since I have programmed and my problem is as follows.

I wish to create a loop that will return to the entry point if the incorrect pay rate is entered.  I want it to print out the error notice if it does no meet the criteria, otherwise go to the you have meet the criteria.  I am also getting an error on data type for the string Laborer as not being defines.   IntelliSense: identifier "Laborer" is undefined.  I have been trying to work it out as seen below.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>  
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int eel;
int hpr;
int kbhit()

void pause()
{
     cout << "Press any key to continue....";
     while(1)
     {            
          if(kbhit())
          {
               break;
          }
     }
}     

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int eel = Laborer;
    int hpr = 0;


    while (hpr < 20.00 || hpr >49.99)
    {
        cout <<"\n\t\t Enter Allowable Pay Rate For The Employee Position."<<endl;
        cout <<"\n\n\t\t =====================================================";
        cout <<"\n\t\t The Allowable Pay Rate Is: 20.00 to 49.99 per hour."<<endl;
        cout <<"\n\n\t\t =====================================================";
        cout <<"\n\t\t Enter Correct Pay Rate For The Position of "<<eel <<": ";
        cin >> hpr;
        cout <<"\n\n\t\t =====================================================";

        if (hpr < 20.00 || hpr >49.99){
        {
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t XX ERROR! ERROR! XX";
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t YOU HAVE ENTERED AN INCORRECT PAY RATE FOR THE POSITION";
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t PLEASE RE-ENTER THE CORRECT RATE FOR THE POSITION";
        }
            if (hpr >= 20  &&  hpr <= 49.99)
            {
                cout<<"\n\n\t\t =========================================================";
                cout<<"\n\t\t You Entered a Correct Pay Rate for the Position of "<< eel <<endl;
                cout<<"\n\t\t Employee Hourly Payroll Rate Is: "<<hpr <<endl;
                cout<<"\n\n\t\t =========================================================";
            }
            pause();          //To stop program to see if the loop is correct
        }
}
```

Comment: `int eel = Laborer;` - where is `Laborer` *supposed* to come from? I don't see it anywhere else so it seems logical that Intellisense can't find it either. (The question/task in the title has nothing to do with the error.)

Comment: // Sets the Work Position For Calcs
    // eel = holds variable for employee pay grade level for wage processing

 if (eelevel = 1){
  eel = Laborer;}
 else if (eelevel = 2){
  eel = Staff;}
 else if (eelevel = 3){
  eel = Assistant Manager;}
 else if (eelevel = 4){
  eel = Manager;}
 cout<<"\n\t\t Employee Work Position Is: "<<eel <<endl;

The program is a demo for processing payroll.  The person imputing the data selects a selection from 4 choices.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an unknown variable 'Laborer' to an integer. By the looks of your goal..
I think what you need to do here is change `int eel = Laborer;` to `string eel = "Laborer";`